# How to Graph x^2 + (y - (x^2)^(1/3))^2 = 1 on a TI-83+

Tags: graph, equation, graphing, ti-basic

I was trying to graph this equation, but it seems that on the TI-83, none of the graphing modes can support this. How would I go about this?

**PS:** I wasn't sure whether-or-not to put this on Math.Stackexchange, or to put it here. If it should go under Math.stackexchange, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just trying to graph the equation, use something like [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) or [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com). These sort of general-purpose tools are much more powerful than graphing calculators, and can graph almost anything you can think of, including implicit equations.

If you want to graph on the TI-83+ specifically, you'll need to do some easy math:

```
x² + (y-x^(2/3))² = 1

(y - x^(2/3))² = 1 - x²

y - x^(2/3) = ±√(1 - x²)

y = x^(2/3) ± √(1 - x²)
```

Now you have Y in terms of X. The TI-83+ series doesn't have a `±` sign, though, so you'll need to graph the two equations as a list. Type this in in `Y=` mode:

```
X^(2/3)+{1,-1}√(1-X²)
```